# How to merge a large set of polygons with Boost Polygon?

Tags: boost, merge, polygon, boost-polygon

I am looking for a way, using Boost Polygon, to read in a large set of polygons from a file, and output the resulting merge or union to a result file. In this case the polygons touch but do not overlap. I can put the data in any format. Not sure if there is a standard used by Boost Polygon. I am also looking for more documentation on the library. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I'm a little confused.  How many input files do you have?  Are they ordered in some way?

Comment: it has to be done pairwise, regardless of how many you may have.  In short take the first two merge them, take the next two merge them, then merge the two intial results, continue this until all polygons have been merged. mind you boost.polygon doesn't work well and is generally buggy, i would suggest using GPC